# How to disable the same choice in two different select html tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

The title is probably confusing, but I will explain. I need to make a frontend of the web page for the online reservation of flights. On the page, there are two dropdown menus where a user has to choose the airport from which he wants to travel, and the destination. So, a part of my task, and a question is, how can I disable the two same choices? Logically, one cannot fly from Paris to Paris.

Comment: in pseudo code: you attach a listener to the change event of each select element.  Each time it changes you disable the matching city in the other element and re-enable any previously disabled cities (if any).

Comment: any source code? how we should know what they look like, what class name they have and so on?

Comment: Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/7q47268o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On load you could, in a sense, *snapshot* the original options via `slice()`. Then in your event listener filter them based off of what was selected in your origin select box. Once you have that select group of options you empty out the destination select box and repolulate it with the filtered ones.

```js
const destination = document.getElementById('destination');

const originalOptions = Array.from(destination.options).slice(0);

document.getElementById('origin').addEventListener('change', e => {
  const currentOptions = Array.from(originalOptions).filter(option => option.value !== e.currentTarget.value);
  
  destination.length = 0;
  
  currentOptions.forEach(option => destination.appendChild(option));
});
```

```html
<select id="origin">
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="australia">Australia</option>
</select>

<select id="destination">
  <option value="london">London</option>
  <option value="paris">Paris</option>
  <option value="australia">Australia</option>
</select>
```